# Processing a seq by accessing its prior elements

Tags: clojure

I want to create a sequence, however to create its every element I need access to the two previous elements. What is the generic way to do such things in clojure ?

So two slightly diff cases -
a) seq is (a b c) when I am processing c I want to have access to a and b ....
b) and having such ability to create the sequence itself by always being able to access th two previous elements.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `iterate` using a vector of two elements and then take the `first` of the resulting sequence.

For example, to create the fibonacci series:

```
user=> (def fib (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [1 1])))
#'user/fib

user=> (take 10 fib)
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
```

Comment: Thanks Raghu, that is beautiful !

Answer (score 3):

partition gives you this nearly for free:

```
(partition-all 3 1 (range 100))
((0 1 2) (1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6) (5 6 7) (6 7 8) ... )
```

then you can map your function over the sequence of partitions:

```
(map my-func (partition-all 3 1 (range 100)))
```

you just need to make your function aware of the fact that the last segment may have less than three elements if your seq is not a multiple of three. if you want to just drop any extras use `partition` instead of `partition-all`

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is one way to do it.   Assume you have a function `g` that takes the last two values as input and produces the next value.

```
(defn f [g x0 x1] 
  (let [s (g x0 x1)] 
    [s (fn [] (f g x1 s))]))
```

Given `g` and two consecutive values in the sequence, `f` returns a pair consisting of the next value and a function that will return the value after that.  You can use `f` as follows to generate an infinite sequence of such pairs:

```
(iterate (fn [[v h]] (h)) (f g x0 x1))
```

To extract just the sequence values, do this:

```
(map first (iterate (fn [[v h]] (h)) (f g x0 x1)))
```

For example:

```
user=> (take 10 (map first (iterate (fn [[v h]] (h)) (f + 0 1))))
(1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89)
```

Comment: Thanks for the generic example.

Comment: (iterate (fn [[v h]] (h)) (f g x0 x1)) - What is the h over here ?

Comment: h is the function that computes the next value.  It was created during the previous iteration and knows what the last two values in the sequence were.  When you call it, it returns the next value in the sequence and the next incarnation of h.

Comment: Raghu's answer accomplishes the same thing without any loss of generality.  In his example, if you replace `+` with `g`, and [1 1] with [x0 x1], you get the generic solution.  My answer was more complicated than it needed to be.